# when i try to download object from s3 bucket : ACCESS DENIED

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a public s3 bucket, when I try to download objects from s3 bucket(amazon console) it is throwing error below

```
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Access Denied</Message>
    <RequestId>REQUESTIDJSDJHDS</RequestId>
    <HostId>FKJGHGGFGJHGFJGHFGJFJGHFGJGHFJGHFGJHGJF</HostId>
</Error>
```

Does anyone have an idea why it is throwing an error?

Comment: What do you mean by "a public s3 bucket"? What makes you think that it is public?

Answer (score 0):

The [**Amazon S3 block public access settings**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXAee.png) can override the permissions for public access. Hence you should check those if you have anything which might impact your access.

Here's [a link](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-troubleshoot-403/) how to troubleshoot that kind of issue.

*The referenced link from above: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-troubleshoot-403/*

PS: Unfortunately, I couldn't write a comment, so an Answer it is.